# TikZ tree alignment with multiline node labels

Tags: formatting, tikz-trees

I'm trying to create a tree structure in tikZ, it looks not too far away from what I want, but a few problems are there:

1. The labels are multiline, which seems to somewhat break the alignment of the edges. The edges should go out in a more centered way.
2. Still lots of overlapping in the tree, probably this can be done if I play some more with the sibling distances? I'm just no yet sure how to get this right, if there's an easier way I'm happy to hear.
3. For *every leaf node* I want to put a text *below the label*. For this I'm not yet sure how to do that at all, since I want to draw a circle around the leaf label (the leaf label is `R\\(0, 0)` for example, but the text should go outside, below the circle.

That's how the tree currently looks like. The alignment/overlap issues are pretty obvious still:

[image]

And the source code (compilable via `pdflatex`) is here

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\pagestyle{empty}             % do not remove
% The settings below are copied from fullpage.sty
\setlength{\textwidth}{\paperwidth}
\addtolength{\textwidth}{-3cm}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\oddsidemargin}{-2.54cm}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{\oddsidemargin}
\setlength{\textheight}{\paperheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headheight}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\headsep}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-\footskip}
\addtolength{\textheight}{-3cm}
\setlength{\topmargin}{1.5cm}
\addtolength{\topmargin}{-2.54cm}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphs.standard}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.text,backgrounds}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[
level distance=20mm,
level 1/.style={sibling distance=50mm},
level 2/.style={sibling distance=30mm},
level 3/.style={sibling distance=20mm},
level 4/.style={sibling distance=10mm},
scale=1.4,transform shape]

\node[label={[align=center]X\\(2, 2)}] {}
  child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(0, 2)}] {}
    child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(0, 1)}] {}
       child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(0, 0)}] {}}
    }
    child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(0, 0)}] {}}
  }
  child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(1, 2)}] {}
    child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(0, 2)}] {}
        child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(0, 0)}] {}}
        child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(0, 1)}] {}
            child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(0, 0)}] {}}
        }
    }
    child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(1, 1)}] {}
        child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(0, 1)}] {}
           child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(0, 0)}] {}}
        }
        child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(1, 0)}] {}
           child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(0, 0)}] {}}
        }
    }
    child {node[label={[align=center]X\\(1, 0)}] {}
        child {node[label={[align=center]Y\\(0, 0)}] {}}
    }
  };

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption*{\huge Question 2 a), the simplified game tree, since we can assume $(a, b) = (b, a)$.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit your document to be compilable. Thank you.

Comment: Re. (2): define 'easier' ;). `forest` can do a lot of this automatically, for example. Is there any pattern to the numbers below the nodes? If this is a game tree `ist-game` might be simpler.

Comment: @cfr sorry I saw your comment too late - yeah it is indeed a game tree. I will have a look at `ist-game` then, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something to point you in the right direction -- as adapted from -- [Control tikz tree](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/531473/control-tikz-tree?rq=1)

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{
    treenode/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners,
    draw, align=center, font=\scriptsize},
    root/.style     = {treenode},
    env/.style      = {treenode},
    every node/.style       = {font=\tiny},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        [
        grow                    = down,
        level 1/.style          = {sibling distance=5cm},
        level 2/.style          = {sibling distance=2.5cm},
        level 3/.style          = {sibling distance=1.5cm},
        level distance          = 1.2cm,
        edge from parent/.style = {draw, edge from parent path={(\tikzparentnode) -- (\tikzchildnode)}},
        ]
        \node [root] {X\\22}
        child { node [env] {Y\\02}
            child { node [env] {X\\01}
                child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 1] {Y\\00}}
            }
            child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 2] {X\\01}
            }
        }
        child { node [env] {Y\\12}
            child{ node [env] {X\\12    }
                child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 4] {Y\\00}
}
                child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 5] {Y\\01}
}
            }
            child{ node [env] {X\\11}
                child { node [env] {Y\\01}
                    child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 6] {X\\00}}
}
                child{ node [env,] {Y\\01}
                                    child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 7] {X\\00}}}
            }
            child{ node [env] {X\\10}
                child{ node [env,label=below:Leaf 8] {Y\\00}
}
            }
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, that's pretty good already. `label=below:Leaf 1`, ok, easier than I thought. he only thing that doesn't work yet is the line break, for me it shows `X11` instead of `X<linebreak>11`. That's why I used the `label` in my source code (which then created awkward overlapping.)

Comment: Ah never mind, line break works when I specify some text property, like `\node [root,align=center] {X\\(2,2)}`

Comment: If you still have a moment, is it possible to color individual edges in this version? If you could give me a hint, that'd be perfect. But thanks a lot already for your help, it's pretty much exactly what I wanted.

Comment: What exactly did you have in mind for colouring @BMBM

Comment: I got it now, thanks! Wanted to color the edges, but it's pretty easy: `child[draw=green] { node ...` all good and thanks again for your help.

Answer (score 0):

With [`istgame`](https://ctan.org/pkg/istgame):

#### ADDED: Using `\xtShowTerminalNodes` and `\istbt`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\usepackage{makecell}
\NewDocumentCommand\mline{O{c}+m}{\makecell[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\setistmathTF*000 % all labels in text mode
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw,circle,minimum size=2.8em}}
\xtShowTerminalNodes[oval node]  %%% show terminal nodes
% tree
\xtdistance{20mm}{70mm}
\istrooto(0){\mline{X\\(2,2)}}           \istb[blue,thick]  \istb[red,very thick]   \endist
% left part: blue
\xtdistance{20mm}{30mm}
\istrooto(L)(0-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,2)$}}    \istb \istbt{}{\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}}[center] \endist
  \xtPayoff*(L-2){\mline{text\\below}}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(L1)(L-1){\mline{X\\$(0,1)$}}   \istbt{}{\mline{Y\\$(0,0)$}}[center]       \endist
  \xtPayoff*(L1-1){\mline{text\\outside}}[below=1.3em]
% right part: red
\xtdistance{20mm}{30mm}
\istrooto(R)(0-2){\mline{Y\\$(1,2)$}}    \istb \istb \istb \endist
\xtdistance{20mm}{15mm}
\istrooto(R1)(R-1){\mline{X\\$(0,2)$}}   \istbt{}{\mline{Y\\$(0,0)$}}[center] \istb \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R1-1){text 1}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R2)(R-2){\mline{X\\$(1,1)$}}   \istb                                \istb \endist
\istrooto(R3)(R-3){\mline{X\\$(1,0)$}}   \istbt{}{\mline{Y\\$(0,0)$}}[center]       \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R3-1){text 2}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R12)(R1-2){\mline{Y\\$(0,1)$}} \istbt{}{\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}}[center]       \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R12-1){text 3}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R21)(R2-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,1)$}} \istbt{}{\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}}[center]       \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R21-1){text 4}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R22)(R2-2){\mline{Y\\$(1,0)$}} \istbt{}{\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}}[center]       \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R22-1){text 5}[below=1.3em]
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

#### Original:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

\usepackage{istgame}

\usepackage{makecell}
\NewDocumentCommand\mline{O{c}+m}{\makecell[#1]{#2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{istgame}[font=\scriptsize]
\setistmathTF*000 % all labels in text mode
\tikzset{oval node/.style={ellipse node,draw,circle}}
% tree: root
\xtdistance{20mm}{70mm}
\istrooto(0){\mline{X\\(2,2)}} 
  \istb[blue,thick]
  \istb[red,very thick]
  \endist
% left part: blue
\xtdistance{20mm}{30mm}
\istrooto(L)(0-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,2)$}}      \istb \istb \endist
  \xtOwner*(L){\mline{text\\left-side}}[left=1.3em,blue]
\istrooto(L1)(L-1){\mline{X\\$(0,1)$}}     \istb       \endist
\istrooto(L2)(L-2){\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}}     \endist
  \xtPayoff*(L2){\mline{text\\below}}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(L11)(L1-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,0)$}}   \endist
  \xtPayoff*(L11){\mline{text\\outside}}[below=1.3em]
% right part: red
\xtdistance{20mm}{30mm}
\istrooto(R)(0-2){\mline{Y\\$(1,2)$}}      \istb \istb \istb \endist
\xtdistance{20mm}{15mm}
\istrooto(R1)(R-1){\mline{X\\$(0,2)$}}     \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(R2)(R-2){\mline{X\\$(1,1)$}}     \istb \istb \endist
\istrooto(R3)(R-3){\mline{X\\$(1,0)$}}     \istb       \endist
\istrooto(R11)(R1-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,0)$}}   \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R11){text 1}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R12)(R1-2){\mline{Y\\$(0,1)$}}   \istb       \endist
\istrooto(R21)(R2-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,1)$}}   \istb       \endist
\istrooto(R22)(R2-2){\mline{Y\\$(1,0)$}}   \istb       \endist
\istrooto(R31)(R3-1){\mline{Y\\$(0,0)$}}   \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R31){text 2}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R121)(R12-1){\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}} \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R121){text 3}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R211)(R21-1){\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}} \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R211){text 4}[below=1.3em]
\istrooto(R221)(R22-1){\mline{X\\$(0,0)$}} \endist
  \xtPayoff*(R221){text 5}[below=1.3em]
\end{istgame}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative, you could use `forest`, which would allow you to format the leaves more easily.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{forest}

\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
for tree={
    parent anchor=south, child anchor=north,
    align=center, 
    s sep=6mm, l sep=8mm,
    if n children=0{draw, circle, minimum size=8mm, inner sep=0pt, fit=band}{}
}
[{X\\(2,2)}
    [{Y\\(0,2)}
        [{X\\(0,1)}
            [{Y\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
        ]
        [{X\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
    ]
    [{Y\\(1,2)}
        [{X\\(0,2)}
            [{Y\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
            [{Y\\(0,1)}
                [{X\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
            ]
        ]
        [{X\\(1,1)}
            [{Y\\(0,1)}
                [{X\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
            ]
            [{Y\\(1,0)}
                [{X\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
            ]
        ]
        [{X\\(1,0)}
            [{Y\\(0,0)}, label=below:text]
        ]
    ]
]
\end{forest}

\end{document}
```